# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for localhost/buddhiedgeserver_db

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a MySQL 5.5 database as follows:

```
public void getCon() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("localhost/buddhiedgeserver_db","root","amma");
    System.out.println("Connection"+con);
}
```

However, it is throwing an exception

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for localhost/buddhiedgeserver_db.

How is this caused and how can I solve it? I am using MyEclipse version 9.1 and I have included the `mysql.jar` in the classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found
> ```

This means that the JDBC URL is not accepted by any of the loaded drivers as per the [`Driver#acceptsURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html#acceptsURL%28java.lang.String%29) contract.

You've correctly loaded the MySQL JDBC driver and it has not thrown a `ClassNotFoundException`, so that part is fine. However, your JDBC URL is completely wrong. It does not conform any syntax as specified in [MySQL JDBC driver documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html). Here's a cite of relevance:

> ### JDBC URL Format
>
> The JDBC URL format for MySQL Connector/J is as follows, with items in square brackets ([, ]) being optional:
>
> ```
> jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database] »
> [?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...
> ```
>
> If the host name is not specified, it defaults to `127.0.0.1`. If the port is not specified, it defaults to `3306`, the default port number for MySQL servers.
>
> ```
> jdbc:mysql://[host:port],[host:port].../[database] »
> [?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...
> ```
>
> Here is a sample connection URL:
>
> ```
> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?profileSQL=true
> ```

Your JDBC URL of `localhost/buddhiedgeserver_db` does absolutely not match the documented MySQL JDBC URL format. Fix it accordingly.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/buddhiedgeserver_db
```